# Refresh page after clearInterval execution

Tags: javascript

I have some trivial code like the following:

```
  var timer_ends = some_ts;

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    time_diff = /* some calculation */

    if ( time_diff <= 0 ) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      // Want to location.reload(true) here but it would recursively run
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Once the timer hits 0 or below, I want to

- clearInterval(timer)
- I want to refresh the page

The problem is, if I refresh the page, the timer will just restart and we'll recursively keep refreshing. What is the best way to execute the `location.reload(true)` once and only once the first time `time_diff` hits 0. Also, if the user is coming to the page for the first time and it's already at 0 it shouldn't refresh.

Comment: Have you tried using cookies?

Comment: can also use localStorage if server is not involved in the timing or tracking

Comment: What is local storage?

Comment: @JermahlWhite plese see docs here [Window localStorage Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Comment: Why do you want to refresh at all?

Comment: Could you please explain why are you trying to refresh the page? I think you are calling `setInterval` on some conditions right? Maybe you could make that condition invalid after page next reload?

Comment: @JonasWilms Random question, but why does my answer being upvoted give me 10 karma instead of 2?

Comment: @electrox upvotes are +10, downvotes -1 and accepted answers +15

Comment: @JonasWilms Ah, ok. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  var timer_ends = some_ts;
  if (Boolean(localStorage.isEnteredBefore)) return;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    time_diff = /* some calculation */

    if ( time_diff <= 0 ) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      // Want to location.reload(true) here but it would recursively run
      localStorage.isEnteredBefore = true;
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Assuming that you are at the function level.

Answer (score 1):

The code for the cookies is from W3Schools. This should be what you want

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var timer_ends = some_ts;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
time_diff = /* some calculation */

if ( time_diff <= 0 ) {
    clearInterval(timer)
    if(getCookie('done')) return
    setCookie('done', true, 30)
    location.reload(true)
     //No need to return here because it's already reloading
}
}, 1000);
```